# Вывод числа в разных системах счисления

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно написать программу (Python), которая получает из первого аргумента командной строки целое число, а после печатает его в разных системах счисления

Результаты должны быть разделены между собой пробелами и идти в следующем порядке: десятичное число, двоичное число, восьмеричное число, шестнадцатеричное число.

Собственно, я написал:

```py
import sys
number = sys.argv[1]
number = int(number)
print(number, bin(number), oct(number), hex(number))
```

но от сервера получаю ответ:

```
Параметры запуска:
> python digit.py 10
Ваш ответ:
10 0b1010 0o12 0xa
Правильный ответ:
10 1010 12 a
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему как правильный ответ принимается округление на 2 символа с начала и как это реализовать в ответе.

Comment: При чем здесь округление-то? Где оно, округление ваше?

Comment: Обратите внимание на Ваш ответ и Правильный ответ. Я только учусь. CrazyElf объяснил более чем доступно.

Comment: Обратите внимание на то, что я вообще не давал ответа. Потому как заданный таким и образом вопрос считаю проявлением неуважения к сообществу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Питон добавляет в начало числа специальные символы, показывающие систему счисления. Это удобно - в коде программы вы тоже можете использовать такие же префиксы и у вас не будет путаницы между константами в разных системах счисления - питон будет точно знать в какой системе вы написали число.

А вот в задаче эти символы не нужны. Можно их просто отрезать от получающейся строки, взяв от каждого такого представления срез `[2:]`

```
print(number, bin(number)[2:], oct(number)[2:], hex(number)[2:])
```

Answer (score 5):

Есть еще такой вариант решения:

```py
>>> number = 10
>>> # двоичная
>>> "{0:b}".format(number)
'1010'
>>> # восьмеричное
>>> "{0:o}".format(number)
'12'
>>> # шестнадцатеричное 
>>> "{0:x}".format(number)
'a'
>>>  # шестнадцатеричное заглавная буква
>>> "{0:X}".format(number)
'A'
```

**UPD** добавлю для `f-string`

```py
>>> number = 10
>>> f"{number:b}" 
'1010'
>>> f"{number:o}" 
'12'
>>> f"{number:x}" 
'a'
>>> f"{number:X}" 
'A'
```